# A scrollview can have only one child

Tags: android

I'm newbie in android programming and I have a problem with "A scrollview can have only one child" what's wrong with my script ? 
I want to know if you have to take ScroolView ? Or how do I fix this problem ? Anyone can edit the scrpt correctly ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="-1"
 android:layout_height="-1">
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="1"
 android:layout_width="-1"
 android:layout_height="-1">

<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="1"
 android:layout_width="-1"
 android:layout_height="-1"
 android:layout_marginLeft="12800"
 android:layout_marginTop="2560">

<TextView
 android:textColor="-1"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:text="2131034150"/>

<Spinner
 android:id="2131165208"
 android:layout_width="94720"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="-1"
 android:prompt="2131034149"/>



<TextView
 android:textColor="-1"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:text="2131034143"/>
<EditText
 android:id="2131165202"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:width="94721"
 android:maxLength="50"/>
<TextView
 android:textColor="-1"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:text="2131034144"/>
<EditText
 android:id="2131165203"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:width="94721"
 android:password="-1"
 android:maxLength="30"/>
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_gravity="3"
 android:orientation="0"
 android:paddingLeft="58881"
 android:paddingBottom="5121"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2">
 <Button
 android:id="2131165204"
 android:layout_width="-2"
 android:layout_height="-2"
 android:text="2131034145"
 android:width="35841"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Error is self explanatory.

A scrollview can have only one direct child.

So make a container layout, which contains all your children. And place that container layout inside a scrollview.

Example hierarchy:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>  <!-- new container layout-->

        <!-- all your children layouts, views -->
    </LinearLayou>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all **-1 -2** etc are invalid values for height and width of views and layouts.

The problem is self-described; a `ScrollView` can't have more than 1 `View` inside it.

Put all your views inside the root `LinearLayout`

Comment: I realize this is an older post, but can you elaborate on the invalidity of **-1 -2**? I've inherited some code with similar values for widths and heights and AndroidStudio is throwing errors. Any thoughts on why this exists, and what to do about it?

Comment: This is very obvious. Any view's height/ width can be either 0 or more. negative height/width is illogical. Views margin and padding can be -ve but  not the size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true in android applications when you are designing a layout you can have only a single child of the ScrollView. and to solve this problem You have to make a  as the child of that  and all the other views and widgets will be inside the  like the following code

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- all other childs (more than one) can be placed here -->

        </Linearlayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

scrollView is not a layout. it is just a container that you can define your layout inside it.
so you must define your layout in the scrollView; then add anything you need to the layout. 
so the views are grandchild of the scroll

your code should be like this